# Solve system of linear equations in sympy

Tags: sympy

I'm learning to use `sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve` to solve a system of linear equations.  I can solve the system all right, but I'm having trouble getting the results assigned to my variables.  It doesn't seem to do the assignment automatically, as I would expect, but returns a one-element set set containing a tuple of the values, and I have to go through some silly contortions to get the values assigned.  Here's my code:

```
from sympy import symbols, ones
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
A= ones(6)
A[0,0]=7
for k in range(1,6):
    A[k,k]=6
b=6*ones(6,1)
p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6 = symbols('p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6')
system = (A,b)
p=linsolve(system,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6)
p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6=tuple(p)[0]
```

Surely there's a more pythonic way of doing this, isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a set is a central idea of `solveset` module (to which `linsolve' belongs). See [Why do we use Sets as an output type?](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#why-do-we-use-sets-as-an-output-type) which includes "Why not use dicts as output?". Yes, it's awkward to deal with: one of open SymPy issues is [The use of sets in solveset makes it very clumsy to get a dictionary of solutions](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11759).

I usually apply `next(iter(...))` to the output of solveset and its analogues.

Your code could be simplified by not listing p1,...p6 individually, keeping it as a tuple of symbols.

```
syms = symbols('p1:7')
system = (A, b)
p = linsolve(system, syms)
p = next(iter(p))
```

Now p is the tuple `(6/13, 36/65, 36/65, 36/65, 36/65, 36/65)`.

The older `solve` method can return a dict directly, but I would not recommend using it to handle a system of linear equations. Besides, SymPy development plan is to transition toward `solveset`, leaving `solve` behind.

Comment: I really like the hint on symbols.

Comment: Looks like this may be in the process of getting fixed. [Added functionality of returning a dictionary as an output of linsolve](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12424)

Comment: Unfortunately that PR has been inactive for more than a year, and is a bit of a mess.

Comment: I didn't even notice it was  a year old! I thought it was it just a few days ago.  Ah, well.